# Error code 1004 on

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to export a query from Access 2010 To Excel 2010 then have conditional formatting inserted.  This code exports the information fine, but throws an error 1004 "Range of object_Global Failed".  The code was build using an excel macro then copying and pasting into my Access module.  Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim objXls As Excel.Application
    Dim MyBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim MySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim MyFile As String


    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 8, "VASL/OCA Report", _
    "G:\shared documents\FSFN OCA Adoption Reconciliations\FY14\VASL-OCA Reconciliation", True

    Set objXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    MyFile = "G:\shared documents\FSFN OCA Adoption Reconciliations\FY14\VASL-OCA Reconciliation.xls"
    objXls.Workbooks.Open ("" & MyFile)
    objXls.Visible = True

    Set MyBook = objXls.Workbooks("VASL-OCA Reconciliation.xls")
    Set MySheet = MyBook.Worksheets("VASL_OCA_Report")

    MySheet.Activate

    Range("G2").Select

    'deleted "scrollRow" lines

    Range("G2:G808").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
        Formula1:="=H2"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
    Range("H808").Select

    'deleted "scrollRow" lines

    Range("H2:H808").Select
    Range("H808").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
        Formula1:="=G2"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True



    End Sub
```

Comment: I removed those few hundred "ScrollRow" lines from your code - they're not relevant here.

Comment: `Range("G2").Select` should be `MySheet.Range("G2").Select` Likewise all subsequent uses of `Range()` or anything else Excel-specific needs to be qualified with either the Excel application object of some other reference you have (such as `MySheet`)

Comment: Which line is indicated as the one that throws the error? You have that information right in front of you, and we don't; it's helpful if you provide **all of the information** you have available when you're asking us to help you.

Comment: Ken, It was throwing the error at line Range("G2").Select

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Const FLDR As String = "G:\shared documents\FSFN OCA Adoption Reconciliations\FY14\"
    Dim objXls As Excel.Application
    Dim MyBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim MySheet As Excel.Worksheet

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 8, "VASL/OCA Report", _
                              FLDR & "VASL-OCA Reconciliation", True

    Set objXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objXls.Visible = True

    Set MyBook = objXls.Workbooks.Open(FLDR & "VASL-OCA Reconciliation.xls")
    Set MySheet = MyBook.Worksheets("VASL_OCA_Report") '<<EDIT

    MySheet.Activate

    With MySheet.Range("G2:G808")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
                              Formula1:="=H2"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
    End With

    With MySheet.Range("H2:H808")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
                            Formula1:="=G2"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for all your help.  The code you wrote is throwing an error 91 at MySheet.Activate